# Empty DataFrame doesn't admit its empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, is-empty

I must not understand something about emptiness when it comes to pandas DataFrames. I have a DF with empty rows but when I isolate one of these rows its not empty.

Here I've made a dataframe:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=[1,2,3], data=[[1,2,3],[1,None,3],[None, None, None],[3,2,1],[4,5,6],[None,None,None],[None,None,None]])
>>> df
     1    2    3
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  1.0  NaN  3.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  3.0  2.0  1.0
4  4.0  5.0  6.0
5  NaN  NaN  NaN
6  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Then I know row '2' is full of  nothing so I check for that...

```
>>> df[2:3].empty
    False
```

Odd. So I split it out into its own dataframe:

```
>>> df1 = df[2:3]
>>> df1
    1   2   3
2 NaN NaN NaN

>>> df1.empty
False
```

How do I check for emptiness (all the elements in a row being None or NaN?)

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html

Comment: empty means its length is 0, not that it has all *nans.

Comment: pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/… check the website example , they already provide the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what `empty` is for. It's meant to check that the size of a series/dataframe is greater than 0, meaning there are rows. For example,

```
df.iloc[1:0]

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1, 2, 3]
Index: []

df.iloc[1:0].empty
True
```

If you want to check that a row has *all `NaNs`*, use `isnull` + `all`:

```
df.isnull().all(1)

0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
dtype: bool
```

For your example, this should do:

```
df[2:3].isnull().all(1).item()
True
```

Note that you can't use `item` if your slice is more than one row in size.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
In [296]: df[5:]
Out[296]:
    1   2   3
5 NaN NaN NaN
6 NaN NaN NaN

In [297]: df[5:].isnull().all(1).all()
Out[297]: True
```

or even better (as [proposed by @IanS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334404/empty-dataframe-doesnt-admit-its-empty/47334457#comment81620287_47334457)):

```
In [300]: df[5:].isnull().all().all()
Out[300]: True
```

Comment: @MaxU I post in a wrong place ....haha , should post under the question ,.,, sorry

Answer (score 2):

You can drop all null values from your selection and check if the result is empty:

```
>>> df[5:].dropna(how='all').empty
True
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to use `isnull()` instead of `empty()`.

```
import pandas 
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=[1,2,3], data=[[1,2,3],[1,None,3],[None, None, None],[3,2,1],[4,5,6],[None,None,None],[None,None,None]])
df[2:3].isnull()
1   2   3
True    True    True
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47334457/4909087 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/47334464/4909087

Answer (score 1):

If you are do not want to count NaN value as real number , this will equal to

```
df.dropna().iloc[5:]
```

You select the line did not exist in your dataframe

```
df.dropna().iloc[5:].empty
Out[921]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dataframe and want to drop all rows containing NaN in each of the columns, you can do this

```
df.dropna(how='all')
```

Noticed that your dataframe also has NaN in one the columns in some cases. If you need to drop the entire row in such case:

```
df.dropna(how='any')
```

After you do this (which ever is your preference) you could check length of dataframe (number of rows it contains) using:

```
len(df)
```